# SVG Textpath behaviour in IE 9

Tags: text, svg, path, d3.js, internet-explorer-9

I'm positioning text labels on the perimeter of a donut/annulus chart. This works fine in Chrome/FF/Opera/Safari. However, in IE9, text close to a 90 degree angle is skewed:

[image]

I'd be keen to know whether there is any way to modify the code to get IE9 to render like the other browsers, or whether the behavior is simply inherent to IE9's implementation of SVG.

Live example at:

http://intensional.org/test/

(Most) relevant section of code is:

```
var pieLabels = svg.selectAll(".pieLabel").data(readyPieData).enter().append("svg:text").attr("class", "pieLabel").attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("dy", "-4").attr("font-size", "17px").attr("id", function(d, i) {
                    return "pieLabel-" + colourData[i].key;
                }).append("svg:textPath")
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
                    return "#piePath-" + colourData[i].key;
                }).attr("id", function(d, i) {
                    return "pieLabelTextPath-" + colourData[i].key;
                })
```

(Note that this code also uses D3.js).

Cheers.

Comment: This bug is still in IE11. I would say try throwing a filter on that bad boy, filters sometimes change what the browser uses to render text